# Code for letting the page load before loading javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have five external JavaScript files that are making the page wait to load before these files are finished loading.

I've been reading a lot about removing render-blocking javascript and it seems like the best way to do this is using the code below to let the page load before loading javascript.

The only problem is that I can't get this code to work on my website.

I've tried to place it both before and after the end-body tag, but nothing is happening.

Am I missing anything? Something wrong in the code or something else I have to do?

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadJSAtOnload() {
        var element = document.createElement("script");
        element.src = "yourjavascripttoload.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }

   if (window.addEventListener)
       window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
   else if (window.attachEvent)
       window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
   else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just put the scripts at the bottom of the page? That's the simplest solution. I wouldn't wait for the `window` to be fully loaded before fetching the scripts, because it's much later than necessary to deal with render-blocking.

Comment: is there an error in the console?

Comment: *"it's not working"* ... so what happens? Any console errors?

Comment: @sihao - No, there is no error in the console.

Comment: @charlietfl - Absolutely nothing is happening. No errors and no changes.

Comment: @JeanetteHaugsdal: I hadn't noticed that you tried it at the bottom of the page, and it didn't work. If that's the case, then it's likely just some syntax issue, or you got the `src` wrong.

Comment: Have you checked browser dev tools network to see if files are even loading? Perhaps paths are incorrect

Comment: ...and are *any* scripts working? Would it be possible that you disabled JavaScript on that page or in the browser in general?

Comment: @charlietfl - Just checked and the files are loading as they should.

Comment: @squint - The scripts are both loading and working as they should.

Comment: Then since there's no answerable issue here, you should probably just delete the question. Glad you got it working.

Comment: @squint - I'm unfortunately not allowed to delete the question. Since I couldn't get any of the codes to work for me, I decided defer loading of javascript instead and this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using async attribute for the script tags,

or like this,

referenced from here,

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-javascript/9781449382308/ch01s03.html

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("get", "file1.js", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState == 4){
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300 || xhr.status == 304){
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.text = xhr.responseText;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
           //Adding to head
          //document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        }

    }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Yikes... why us XHR to get a script? And are you going to give credit for where you copied this code?

Comment: yes you are correct, it can cause cross origin issue too

Answer (score 0):

First check the exact location of your external script file. Then put this script before the `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.setAttribute('src', 'http://yourdomian.com/yourjavascripttoload.js');
   script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```

or in Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.getScript("yourjavascripttoload.js", function(){
       alert("Script loaded and executed.");
     });
});
```